# Java Generics Conundrum

Tags: java, generics

Here's the relevant code:

```
public interface Artifact {}    
public interface Bundle implements Artifact {}
public interface Component implements Artifact {}

public interface State<T extends Artifact> {
    void transition(T artifact, State<T> nextState);
}
```

This allows me to define this enum:

```
enum BundleState implements State<Bundle> {

    A, B, C;

    public void transition(Bundle bundle, State<Bundle> nextState) {}
    }
}
```

But the method signature that I want is:

```
    public void transition(Bundle bundle, BundleState nextState) {}
    }
```

But this does not compile. Obviously the problem lies with how I've defined `T` in the `State` interface, but I can't figure out know how to fix it.

Thanks,
Don

Answer (score 10):

Things might start getting unwieldly, but you *could* change `State` to:

```
public interface State<T extends Artifact, U extends State<T, U>> {
    void transition(T artifact, U nextState);
}
```

And change BundleState to:

```
public enum BundleState implements State<Bundle, BundleState> {
    A, B, C;

    public void transition(Bundle bundle, BundleState nextState) {}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Methods are not contravariant in Java. You could overload and have both, but there wouldn't be much point.

Possibly, you could declare `State` as something like:

```
public interface State<THIS extends State<THIS, A>, A extends Artifact> {
    void transition(A artifact, THIS nextState);
}
```

`THIS extends State<THIS, A>` is possibly wrong. It depends on what you want to do.

(Single letter enum constants are probably a bad idea, particularly when mixed with generics parameters.)

Answer (score 1):

transition(Bundle, BundleState) doesn't match your current State interface unless you change it as suggested here by others. You could also preserve the interface with

```
enum BundleState implements Artifact, State<BundleState> {
    A, B, C;
    public void transition(BundleState bundle, State<BundleState> nextState)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
enum BundleState implements State<Bundle> 
{
    A, B, C;

    public void transition(Bundle bundle, BundleState nextState) 
    {
        transition(bundel, (State<Bundle>)nextState);
    }

    public void transition(Bundle bundle, State<Bundle> nextState) {}
}
```